# Is it possible to override default code formatt of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, workspace

I have java code style formatter of Eclipse (for that matter it can be formatter of the other language also). When I import he format then it is saved in the workspace and that is applicable for that workspace.

I want code format/style imported and saved in the Eclipse setting itself so that this Eclipse used by anyone gets the format whatever workspace they use.

Is it possible to override the default format? Do I have to write my own plugin?

Thanks,

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? Let developers manage their own style, and use a formatter after code check-in.

Comment: If you want to ensure your projects use the custom format, specify it for the Project, rather than letting the project inherit from the workspace *(default)*.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The reason why I am trying to do this is that the format is same across projects/repositories and developers do not have to apply this in all the projects as long as they use this customised eclipse (unless they specifically want to do this as you mentioned).

Comment: @Andreas That is possible but exploring the possibility if Eclipse has such an option which allows overriding the default format

Comment: @Mozaffar Looks the same on Eclipse Neon as on Eclipse Indigo so far as I can tell.  So answer below should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following in the Java perspective, Eclipse version Indigo...

```
click Window -> Preferences
expand Java -> Code Style
click Formatter
```

This will get you to the `Formatter` screen below.  Follow the link on the top right
and see if this provides you with what you are requesting.

[image]

Configure Project Specific Settings screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this sets the preferences in the project. I was looking for the preferences with the eclipse packaging itself so it is applicable everywhere with all the projects.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted settings to be present in the eclipse packaging itself so that these settings (code format, template, spacing strategy etc.) are not repeated at every project and workspace level.

I got a way (at least it works on Linux with neon version). Here are the steps

1. Open eclipse with some workspace location
2. Apply all the settings like code formatting, template, Editor
   preferences and all other preferred settings present in **Window ->
   Preferences** Press **OK**. it will save the preferences.
3. Go to **File -> Export -> General -> Preferences** and press *Next*
4. Make sure *Export all* is checked and then provide the *To
   Preference File* location and then Click *Finish*
5. Now open the exported file in you favorite editor
6. You will observe it is like a properties file with each property     prefixed with **/instance/** or **/configuration/** (these are preference scopes). Remove all these prefixes (after that all the properties will look like org.* or net.* etc.). You will also see some workspace path related     properties are present in this file, either remove them or change to    appropriate one.
7. Save this file with some name say *my-eclipse-preference.epf* and copy
   this file to your eclipse location (where eclipse start file is
   present, say ECLIPSE_HOME)
8. Open **$ECLIPSE_HOME/configuration/config.ini** and add a line with
   the property *puluginCoustomization=my-eclipse-preference.epf* at the end and save config.ini.
9. Restart the eclipse, you will find your settings are present even if you open with empty/new workspace. If you are starting from terminal then got to
   the *ECLIPSE_HOME* directory first and then start.
10. If you want to start from the terminal but you want to avoid going
     to the directory to start (i.e. starting from any location) then you should store the file *my-eclipse-preference.epf* at some standard location and have the value of *puluginCoustomization* with full path in config.ini.

Hope this helps.